# Como uso un parametro como expresion de conexion en un rdl?

Tags: report, rdlc

Soy principiante y he visto que en algunos rdl usan como expresión de conexión un parámetro, quisiera saber como hacer eso y donde se configura la entrada de ese parámetro, he estado viendo videos pero no explican como hacer eso he visto que usan visual estudio, yo he estado usado el report builder de microsoft. Gracias de antemano.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]